# Hibernate JPA JoinTable referenciar outra coluna como identificador ao invés da chave primária

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, relacionamento, referência

Olá, com base na seguinte modelagem abaixo, gostaria de mapear dois relacionamentos M:N. Um entre Médico e Equipe_Parto e outra entre Enfermeiro e Equipe_Parto. Sei que desses relacionamentos surgem duas tabelas de associação que chamei de Equipe_Medica e Equipe_Enfermagem, respectivamente.

[Modelagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6UGy.png)

Como pode ser visto, as entidades Medico e Enfermeiro possuem um relaciomento do tipo indentificado com a entidade Funcionario, sendo assim, estas herdam todos os seus atributos, inclusive a chave primária cpf da entidade Funcionario.

Gostaria de:

1. Realizar um mapeamento que permitisse eu referenciar o atributo crm da entidade Medico, dentro da tabela de associação Equipe_Medica ao invés de sua chave primaria cpf (herdada da entidade Funcionario).
2. De forma semelhante ao caso acima, realizar um mapeamento que permitisse eu referenciar o atributo inscricaoCoren da entidade Enfermeiro, dentro da tabela de associação Equipe_Enfermagem ao invés de sua chave primária cpf (também herdada da entidade Funcionario).

Para exemplificar o que eu fiz segue o código abaixo e o erro retornado usando como base as classes Medico, Funcionario, e EquipeParto.

**Classe Funcionario:**

```
package com.healthcare.babysoft.models;

import com.healthcare.babysoft.enums.Status;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_FUNCIONARIO")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class FuncionarioModel implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private String cpf;
private String nome;
@Column(unique = true)
private String email;
private String senha;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Status status;

public FuncionarioModel() {}

public FuncionarioModel(String cpf, String nome, String email, String senha, Status status) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
    this.nome = nome;
    this.email = email;
    this.senha = senha;
    this.status = status;
}

public String getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}

public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    FuncionarioModel that = (FuncionarioModel) o;
    return cpf.equals(that.cpf);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(cpf);
}
}
```

**Classe Medico:**

```
package com.healthcare.babysoft.models;

import com.healthcare.babysoft.enums.Status;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_MEDICO")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "cpf_funcionario")
public class MedicoModel extends FuncionarioModel {
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String crm;

@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "especialidade_id", nullable = false)
private EspecialidadeModel especialidade;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "TB_EQUIPE_MEDICA",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "crm", referencedColumnName = "crm")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "equipe_parto_id")})
private Set<EquipePartoModel> equipesParto = new HashSet<>();

public MedicoModel() {}

public MedicoModel(String crm) {
    this.crm = crm;
}

public MedicoModel(String cpf, String nome, String email, String senha, Status status, String crm, EspecialidadeModel especialidade) {
    super(cpf, nome, email, senha, status);
    this.crm = crm;
}

public String getCrm() {
    return crm;
}

public void setCrm(String crm) {
    this.crm = crm;
}

public EspecialidadeModel getEspecialidade() {
    return especialidade;
}

public void setEspecialidade(EspecialidadeModel especialidade) { this.especialidade = especialidade; }

public Set<EquipePartoModel> getEquipesParto() {
    return equipesParto;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
    MedicoModel that = (MedicoModel) o;
    return crm.equals(that.crm);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), crm);
}
}
```

**Classe Equipe_Parto:**

```
package com.healthcare.babysoft.models;

import com.healthcare.babysoft.enums.DOULA;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_EQUIPE_PARTO")
public class EquipePartoModel implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long equipePartoId;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private DOULA doula;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "equipesParto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<MedicoModel> equipeMedica = new HashSet<>();

public EquipePartoModel() {}

public EquipePartoModel(Long equipePartoId, DOULA doula) {
    this.equipePartoId = equipePartoId;
    this.doula = doula;
}

public Long getEquipePartoId() {
    return equipePartoId;
}

public void setEquipePartoId(Long equipePartoId) {
    this.equipePartoId = equipePartoId;
}

public DOULA getDoula() {
    return doula;
}

public void setDoula(DOULA doula) {
    this.doula = doula;
}

public Set<MedicoModel> getEquipeMedica() {
    return equipeMedica;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    EquipePartoModel that = (EquipePartoModel) o;
    return equipePartoId.equals(that.equipePartoId);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(equipePartoId);
}
```

}

**Arquivo import.sql:**

```
INSERT INTO tb_mae (cpf, nome, data_nascimento, telefone, endereco, numero, bairro, complemento, uf, cep) VALUES ('56789012345', 'Maria Antonieta', '1981-08-18', '11912345678', 'Rua Azul', 100, 'Lapa', 'Casa', 'ES', '45820000');
INSERT INTO tb_ficha_paciente (cpf_paciente, tipo_sanguineo, soro_positivo, hipertensao, diabetes, medicacao_controlada, peso, altura) VALUES ('56789012345', 'O+', 'NÃO', 'NÃO', 'NÃO', 'NÃO', 60.0, 1.58);
INSERT INTO tb_recem_nascido (nome, data_nascimento, sexo, peso, altura, condicao, cpf_pai, cpf_mae) VALUES ('Ester Antonieta Souza', '2020-03-20 10:20:30', 'F', 3.50, 40.0, 'SAUDÁVEL', '12345678900', '56789012345');
INSERT INTO tb_especialidade (nome) VALUES ('Obstetra');
INSERT INTO tb_especialidade (nome) VALUES ('Anestesista');
INSERT INTO tb_especialidade (nome) VALUES ('Pediatra');
INSERT INTO tb_funcionario (cpf, nome, email, senha, status) VALUES ('12345678901', 'Antonio Braz', 'antonio@gmail.com', '123456', 'ATIVO');
INSERT INTO tb_funcionario (cpf, nome, email, senha, status) VALUES ('23456789012', 'João Silva', 'joao@gmail.com', '123456', 'ATIVO');
INSERT INTO tb_funcionario (cpf, nome, email, senha, status) VALUES ('34567890123', 'Maria Souza', 'maria@gmail.com', '123456', 'ATIVO');
INSERT INTO tb_medico(cpf_funcionario, crm, especialidade_id) VALUES ('12345678901', 'BA123456', 1);
INSERT INTO tb_enfermeiro(cpf_funcionario, inscricao_coren) VALUES ('23456789012', 'BA123456T1');
INSERT INTO tb_parto(cpf_mae, data_parto, tipo_parto, parto_risco, multifetal, observacao) VALUES ('56789012345', '2020-03-20 10:20:30', 'NORMAL', 'NÃO', 'NÃO', 'Parto sem complicações');
INSERT INTO tb_equipe_parto(doula) VALUES ('SIM');
INSERT INTO tb_equipe_medica(crm, equipe_parto_id) VALUES ('BA123456', 1);
```

Erro no console:

```
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@4a52674f

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.3)

2022-12-20 22:48:03.100  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.babysoft.BabysoftApplication         : Starting BabysoftApplication using Java 17.0.3 on DESKTOP-R8ABUE3 with PID 19668 (C:\BD\babysoft\backend\target\classes started by BEGA in C:\BD\babysoft\backend)
2022-12-20 22:48:03.102  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.babysoft.BabysoftApplication         : The following 1 profile is active: "test"
2022-12-20 22:48:03.171  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-12-20 22:48:03.171  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-12-20 22:48:04.149  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-12-20 22:48:04.282  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 117 ms. Found 9 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-12-20 22:48:05.106  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-12-20 22:48:05.118  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-12-20 22:48:05.118  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-12-20 22:48:05.241  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-12-20 22:48:05.241  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2069 ms
2022-12-20 22:48:05.283  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-12-20 22:48:05.570  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-12-20 22:48:05.586  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'
2022-12-20 22:48:05.752  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-12-20 22:48:05.852  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.10.Final
2022-12-20 22:48:06.080  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-12-20 22:48:06.195  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
Hibernate: drop table if exists tb_enfermeiro CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop table if exists tb_equipe_medica CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop table if exists tb_equipe_parto CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop table if exists tb_especialidade CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop table if exists tb_ficha_paciente CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop table if exists tb_funcionario CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop table if exists tb_mae CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop table if exists tb_medico CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop table if exists tb_parto CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop table if exists tb_recem_nascido CASCADE 
Hibernate: create table tb_enfermeiro (inscricao_coren varchar(255), cpf_funcionario varchar(255) not null, primary key (cpf_funcionario))
Hibernate: create table tb_equipe_medica (crm varchar(255) not null, equipe_parto_id bigint not null, primary key (crm, equipe_parto_id))
Hibernate: create table tb_equipe_parto (equipe_parto_id bigint generated by default as identity, doula varchar(255), primary key (equipe_parto_id))
Hibernate: create table tb_especialidade (especialidade_id integer generated by default as identity, nome varchar(255), primary key (especialidade_id))
Hibernate: create table tb_ficha_paciente (cpf_paciente varchar(255) not null, altura double, diabetes varchar(255), hipertensao varchar(255), medicacao_controlada varchar(255), peso double, soro_positivo varchar(255), tipo_sanguineo varchar(255), primary key (cpf_paciente))
Hibernate: create table tb_funcionario (cpf varchar(255) not null, email varchar(255), nome varchar(255), senha varchar(255), status varchar(255), primary key (cpf))
Hibernate: create table tb_mae (cpf varchar(255) not null, bairro varchar(40) not null, cep varchar(8) not null, complemento varchar(50) not null, data_nascimento date not null, endereco varchar(40) not null, nome varchar(50) not null, numero integer not null, telefone varchar(20) not null, uf varchar(2) not null, primary key (cpf))
Hibernate: create table tb_medico (crm varchar(255) not null, cpf_funcionario varchar(255) not null, especialidade_id integer not null, primary key (cpf_funcionario))
Hibernate: create table tb_parto (parto_id bigint generated by default as identity, multifetal varchar(255), observacao varchar(255), parto_risco varchar(255), tipo_parto varchar(255), data_parto timestamp, cpf_mae varchar(255), primary key (parto_id))
Hibernate: create table tb_recem_nascido (data_nascimento timestamp not null, altura double not null, condicao varchar(255) not null, cpf_pai varchar(50), nome varchar(50) not null, peso double not null, sexo char(1) not null, cpf_mae varchar(255) not null, primary key (data_nascimento, cpf_mae))
Hibernate: alter table tb_enfermeiro add constraint UK_nas4eive3qraprtht6nqop8qu unique (inscricao_coren)
Hibernate: alter table tb_especialidade add constraint UK_5yxwih25sd0ugmjuqfqkvi8cx unique (nome)
Hibernate: alter table tb_funcionario add constraint UK_onjc1xoei8x59dt76x2xnd3wc unique (email)
Hibernate: alter table tb_medico add constraint UK_e3rshjf73lyqjlu8cotj0t7vr unique (crm)
Hibernate: alter table tb_parto add constraint UKrvovdhthbik01tdci6ib9tdl5 unique (data_parto, cpf_mae)
Hibernate: alter table tb_enfermeiro add constraint FK8m7lw61jopcqn262uiagx2hac foreign key (cpf_funcionario) references tb_funcionario
Hibernate: alter table tb_equipe_medica add constraint FKm9rpj48afvqg2ta98hv9b60bf foreign key (equipe_parto_id) references tb_equipe_parto
Hibernate: alter table tb_equipe_medica add constraint FKgkiu8hhtqw7nlnuy2ysrf8fhu foreign key (crm) references tb_medico
Hibernate: alter table tb_ficha_paciente add constraint FKq58mhjxx7yysxpjx5opw7nx85 foreign key (cpf_paciente) references tb_mae
Hibernate: alter table tb_medico add constraint FK1sow3tf9c28ei7nlrovt2xvvb foreign key (especialidade_id) references tb_especialidade
Hibernate: alter table tb_medico add constraint FKk00rvf6j7jn8i0vp6r0csr9bm foreign key (cpf_funcionario) references tb_funcionario
Hibernate: alter table tb_parto add constraint FKr40a9ks6w1y6tt0aqn9vcw8g7 foreign key (data_parto, cpf_mae) references tb_recem_nascido
Hibernate: alter table tb_recem_nascido add constraint FKkgyakmb1qgtu5r0qy0v3ark0v foreign key (cpf_mae) references tb_mae
2022-12-20 22:48:07.028  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'file:/C:/BD/babysoft/backend/target/classes/import.sql'
Hibernate: INSERT INTO tb_mae (cpf, nome, data_nascimento, telefone, endereco, numero, bairro, complemento, uf, cep) VALUES ('56789012345', 'Maria Antonieta', '1981-08-18', '11912345678', 'Rua Azul', 100, 'Lapa', 'Casa', 'ES', '45820240')
Hibernate: INSERT INTO tb_ficha_paciente (cpf_paciente, tipo_sanguineo, soro_positivo, hipertensao, diabetes, medicacao_controlada, peso, altura) VALUES ('56789012345', 'O+', 'NÃO', 'NÃO', 'NÃO', 'NÃO', 60.0, 1.58)
Hibernate: INSERT INTO tb_recem_nascido (nome, data_nascimento, sexo, peso, altura, condicao, cpf_pai, cpf_mae) VALUES ('Ester Antonieta Souza', '2020-03-20 10:20:30', 'F', 3.50, 40.0, 'SAUDÁVEL', '12345678900', '56789012345')
Hibernate: INSERT INTO tb_especialidade (nome) VALUES ('Obstetra')
Hibernate: INSERT INTO tb_especialidade (nome) VALUES ('Anestesista')
Hibernate: INSERT INTO tb_especialidade (nome) VALUES ('Pediatra')
Hibernate: INSERT INTO tb_funcionario (cpf, nome, email, senha, status) VALUES ('12345678901', 'Antonio Braz', 'antonio@gmail.com', '123456', 'ATIVO')
Hibernate: INSERT INTO tb_funcionario (cpf, nome, email, senha, status) VALUES ('23456789012', 'João Silva', 'joao@gmail.com', '123456', 'ATIVO')
Hibernate: INSERT INTO tb_funcionario (cpf, nome, email, senha, status) VALUES ('34567890123', 'Maria Souza', 'maria@gmail.com', '123456', 'ATIVO')
Hibernate: INSERT INTO tb_medico(cpf_funcionario, crm, especialidade_id) VALUES ('12345678901', 'BA123456', 1)
Hibernate: INSERT INTO tb_enfermeiro(cpf_funcionario, inscricao_coren) VALUES ('23456789012', 'BA123456T1')
Hibernate: INSERT INTO tb_parto(cpf_mae, data_parto, tipo_parto, parto_risco, multifetal, observacao) VALUES ('56789012345', '2020-03-20 10:20:30', 'NORMAL', 'NÃO', 'NÃO', 'Parto sem complicações')
Hibernate: INSERT INTO tb_equipe_parto(doula) VALUES ('SIM')
Hibernate: INSERT INTO tb_equipe_medica(crm, equipe_parto_id) VALUES ('BA123456', 1)
2022-12-20 22:48:07.045  WARN 19668 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "INSERT INTO tb_equipe_medica(crm, equipe_parto_id) VALUES ('BA123456', 1)" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "INSERT INTO tb_equipe_medica(crm, equipe_parto_id) VALUES ('BA123456', 1)" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applyImportSources(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:514) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at com.healthcare.babysoft.BabysoftApplication.main(BabysoftApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKGKIU8HHTQW7NLNUY2YSRF8FHU: PUBLIC.TB_EQUIPE_MEDICA FOREIGN KEY(CRM) REFERENCES PUBLIC.TB_MEDICO(CPF_FUNCIONARIO) ('BA123456')"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO tb_equipe_medica(crm, equipe_parto_id) VALUES ('BA123456', 1) [23506-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:508) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRowOwnTable(ConstraintReferential.java:311) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:252) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireConstraints(Table.java:1172) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:1190) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:188) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:135) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.dml.DataChangeStatement.update(DataChangeStatement.java:74) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:169) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:252) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:252) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    ... 38 common frames omitted

2022-12-20 22:48:07.046  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-12-20 22:48:07.053  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-12-20 22:48:08.062  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-12-20 22:48:08.098  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-12-20 22:48:08.110  INFO 19668 --- [  restartedMain] c.h.babysoft.BabysoftApplication         : Started BabysoftApplication in 5.506 seconds (JVM running for 6.395)
```

Comment: Pode ser algo na sua montagem da Entidade ou configuração do dialeto da conexão. Nesse link há algumas soluções, de uma olhada se alguma dela pode te atender. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191294/hibernate-error-executing-ddl-via-jdbc-statement

Comment: Com relação as entidades e ao dialeto está tudo ok. Acredito que o fato de utilizar a anotação @JoinTable, a JPA, me obrigue a referenciar as chaves primárias das entidades envolvidas no mapeamento. Estou testando uma outra alternativa. Caso funcione, postarei aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver. Ao invés de utilizar criar uma associação utilizando uma JoinTable eu crie outras duas tabelas adicionais do tipo 1:N, e com isso pude referenciar os campos que eu desejava. No final das contas a modelagem ficou da seguinte forma:
[Modelagem_atualizada](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv5Hg.png)

Fica aqui o meu agradecimento ao @HOMER_JAMAICANO

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).